# Sobrecarga del constructor

Tags: php

Estoy intentando conseguir sobrecargar el constructor de una clase para un ejercicio de clase, aunque en el ejercicio no lo pide explicita mente, yo empeñe en buscar una forma de hacerlo con sobrecarga del constructor.
El ejercicio dice así:
Crea una clase Persona con tres propiedades (nombre, fecha de nacimiento y sexo) que no deben ser accesibles directamente desde el exterior.
Define un constructor que pueda recibir como parámetro las 3 propiedades o únicamente las dos primeras. En este caso el valor que debe tomar el atributo sexo es ‘H’.

```php
class Persona{
    private $nombre;
    private $fechaNacimiento;
    private $sexo;

    function __construct(){
        $params = func_get_args();
        $num_params = func_num_args();
        $funcion_constructor = '__construct'.$num_params;

        if (method_exists($this, $funcion_constructor)) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $funcion_constructor), $params);
        }
    }

    function __construct0(){
        $this->__construct1("Anonimo");
    }

    function __construct1($nombre, $fecha){
        $this->__construct2($nombre, $fecha, "H");
    }

    function __construct2($nombre, $fecha, $sexo){
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
        $this->fechaNacimiento = $fecha;
        $this->sexo = $sexo;
    }

    public function getDatos(){
        if ($this->sexo == "H") {
            $s = "Hombre";
        }else if ($this->sexo == "M") {
            $s = "Mujer";
        }else {
            $s = "Desconocido";
        }

        return $this->nombre." ".$this->fechaNacimiento." ".$s;
    }
}
```

A la hora de hacer la instancia lo hago así:

```php
$p1 = new Persona("Raquel", "20/01/1988", "M");
$p2 = new Persona("Andres", "15/05/1987");
echo $p1->getDatos();
echo "<br />";
echo $p2->getDatos();
echo "<br />";
```

Este código lo saque de [aquí](https://desarrolloweb.com/articulos/sobrecarga-constructores-php.html)

Comment: Disculpa pero no me queda claro ¿cual es la pregunta?

Comment: En PHP sólo puede existir 1 constructor.

Comment: En PHP 5 solo puede haber un constructor, no sé si PHP 7 ya lo permita

Comment: En `__construct0` deberías lanzar una excepción, porque es obligatorio enviar al menos 2 parámetros. Aparte de eso, ¿hay algún error en tu clase?

Comment: @Marcos lo que quiero es una forma de simular una sobrecarga del constructor, buscando encontré la que puse

Comment: @Triby Me da el siguiente error, aunque solo cuando hago la instancia: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Persona::__construct2(), 2 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservidor\index.php on line 65 and exactly 3 expected in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservidor\index.php:78 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webservidor\index.php(65): Persona->__construct2('Andres', '15/05/1987') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\webservidor\index.php(99): Persona->__construct('Andres', '15/05/1987') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\webservidor\index.php on line 78

Comment: Ya lo arregle, tuve que añadir otra función entre la ```function __construct0()``` y la ```function __construct1($nombre, $fecha)``` que se llama: ```function __construct1($nombre)``` y las que están a continuación de la que añadí las renombre para que sigan el orden